# pyspark column character replacement

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, replace

So I have an Azure Data Factory ingestion that's using a Databricks notebook to parse illegal column name characters before saving it. This eventually put into a separate database.table. The code I decided on works, but is really inefficient....like five hours for an excel sheet that has over 350 columns. I need another approach that is more efficient to cut run times down.

```
    #Replace illegal column names
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.lstrip())
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.rstrip())
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace(">", "greaterthan"))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("?", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("!", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("#", "number"))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("&", "and"))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("$", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("/", "_"))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("-", "_"))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace(",", "_"))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("(", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace(")", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("{", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("}", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("=", "equals"))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("\n", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("\t", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("'", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace(".", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("+", "plus"))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace(":", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("...", ""))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace(" ", "_"))
for column in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("__", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your way is inefficient because it has a lot of unnecessary iterations, you can rename the original column applying all rules in a single iteration, following this idea:

```py
import re

re_blank = re.compile(r'''[?!$(){}\n\t':._]''')
re_underscore = re.compile(r'''[-/, ]''')

for column in df.columns:
    renamed = (column
               .strip()
               .replace(">", "greaterthan")
               .replace("#", "number")
               .replace("&", "and")
               .replace("=", "equals")
               .replace("+", "plus"))

    renamed = re_blank.sub('', renamed)
    renamed = re_underscore.sub('_', renamed)
    renamed = renamed.replace("__", "")
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, renamed)
```